# Contains in formula - compare two fields

Tags: formula

I have a case where I have to compare two fields one is a TEXT field and the second is a MultiPicklist. If MultiPicklistField__c contains value from TextField__c give me a true if not give a false.

So the MultiPicklist can have a values like A;B and when TextField__c is A mark checkbox on TRUE

```
IF(CONTAINS("$User.TextField__c", MultiPicklistField__c), TRUE, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multi-picklist you need to use INCLUDES.
For example:

```
INCLUDES(MultiPicklistField__c, "sometext")
```

There is no need to use IF formula since INCLUDES returns TRUE/FALSE already.

Check out the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5).

Comment: I try to use your formula but I have error

Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'INCLUDES()'. Expected Text Literal, received Text

 $User.TextField__c field is a FORMULA (TEXT)

Comment: Ah yes, it needs to have a literal text, it cannot be a field/formula. What can be the value of `TextField__c`? Is that a picklist?